# Query on how to clear the memory of objects of derived class

Tags: c++, qt

I have situation in which I am getting a crash on clearing the memories in destructor. Please see the code below

C++ Code:

```
class Key{
    ....
};

Class Object {
    ...
};

Class E {

    private:
        vector<Object> m_vector;
};

Class A {
    public:
        virtual void check()=0;
    protected:
        hashmap<Key*,E*> myMap; 
};

A:~A() {
    EMapItr eMapItr = myMap.beginRandom();
    for(; eMaptr; ++eMapItr) {
        delete eMapItr.value();
}
E:~E() {
    m_vector.clear();
}


class B: public A {
    public:
        virtual void check()
    private:
        DB* db;
} 

void B::check() {
    db->create(&myMap);
}

QT Code:

class MyQtAction {
public:
    void act() ;
private:
    GUIObject* guiWindowObject
};
MyQtAction::act() {
    A* aobj = new B();
    if(!guiWindowObject) {
        guiWindowObject = new GUIObject(aobj);
    }
};

class GUIObject:public QWidget {
private:
    A* guiAobj; 
 };

 GUIObject:GUIObject(A* obj) { 
    guiAobj= obj;
 }
 GUIObject:~GUIObject {
 }
```

Now Can you please where shall I delete the point of A class because   object of A is created multiple times

Comment: `A* aobj = new B();` can be unused and not deleted - it will leaks memory

Comment: Use Virtual destructor in Class A to avoid memory leak

Comment: The problem might stem from you adding something to `A::myMap` that you haven't allocated with `new`. For a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you don't need the Qt code nor almost anything else, just the `myMap` and adding pointers to it.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you have created your own hash-map type instead of using e.g. [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), or even [`QMap`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html)? I'm also a little worried that you use a pointer as the key for the map, does the map class hash on the actual pointer or the data the pointer points to?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Qt, I'd suggest your leverage on its very powerful "Object Trees & Ownership" model that comes for free with it:

> QObjects organize themselves in object trees. When you create a
>   QObject with another object as parent, it's added to the parent's
>   children() list, and is deleted when the parent is.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html

- derive your classes from QObject, and make them use/require a QObject as parent parameter.
- then, at instanciation, specify the parent object (this is why there
  is a "parent" parameter all over the place in Qt's constructors
  documentation),
- no more `delete`, enjoy automagic deletion of child, grand child,
  grand-grand child etc when the parent is deleted / goes out of scope.

You can use the `QObject::dumpObjectTree()` to visualise the parent/child tree at run time.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dumpObjectTree

Now, there *can* be some tricky situations (see the doc above) which may require manual explicit `delete`, but in my experience 95% of the time it's fine - and in any case much less error prone than handling this yourself as your application grow big and complex. If you use Qt, you definitely want to use this. It's a great feature of the framework.

EDIT:

Now, about the context of your development and "is it C++ or is it Qt"?

- If you want to learn C++ the hard and good way (and just add a bit of
  fun with a few Qt graphical widgets), then you *must* understand the
  destructors and be able to to handle it by yourself.
- On the other hand, if you want to create a serious Qt application,
  then *you must embrace the Qt framework as a whole*, and this
  parent/child QObject fundamental base class, from which all others Qt's
  class are derived is fundamental and oh-so-useful. There are a couple
  of others root fundamental Qt concept, such as [No Copy Constructor or Assignment
  Operator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor-or-assignment-operator), with
  its very important consequence that you'll use pointers everywhere,
  and its rationale
  [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/object.html#identity-vs-value), or Qt's
  "no exceptions" motto, explained
  [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/exceptionsafety.html), from
  "historical and practical reasons" to quote the documentation, and if
  I'm not mistaken was not supported at all before Qt>=5. *When doing
  Qt, do full Qt. The hardcore C++, thought available, is buried under the
  surface.*

Answer (score 0):

You should delete it in act(). Otherwise you may lose trace of it. It is not a good idea to initialize memory and then transfer the pointer to an object (unless of course the situation requires it). My advice is to move the new for A in the GUIObject's constructor. When GUIObject is deleted you can safely eliminate A without running into a double memory free.

Something like this:

```
class GUIObject {
    A* aobj;
public:
    GUIObject();
    ~GUIObject();
};

GUIObject::GUIObject()
{
    A* aobj = new B();
}

GUIObject::~GUIObject()
{
    delete aobj;
}
```